# component not loading in angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am creating a project Where I have a homepage with a sidebar. On click of the sidebar, the component is supposed to be loaded on the right hand side of the page. I have done the routing for the same too. Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <app-mentor-sidebar></app-mentor-sidebar>
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 main">
        <div class="row">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="#" >
                        <em class="fa fa-home"></em>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a [routerLink]=""> {{breadcum}}
                        </a></li>

                </ol>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=goback(); >Back</button>
            </div>
            <router-outlet>   </router-outlet>

        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

The  is supposed to load the html component but nothing is happening.

Comment: you did not declare the component that load in `[routerLink]=""` plaese learn here:https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: for example you want go to "dashbord" set `[routerLink]="['/dashbord']"` and do not forget to create a array of router--https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: So how are you expecting the component to load without providing its link?

Comment: The problem was in the page that <router-outlet> was supposed to load. Defined and declared the functions and that solved the problem.